# Sorting Mysql results based on a modified column

Tags: mysql, regex, perl

I have a mysql query which outputs 6 columns of related data, I'm specifically interested in having the results sorted alphabetically by a certain modified column. The unmodified results from that column look like this:

```
... | 0001: Some text here        |...
... | 0002: Flipped text here     |...
... | 0003: About some more text  |...
```

The '0001:' portion should not be displayed. Currently, I have a Perl subroutine which removes that portion from being displayed, but I don't know how I can get all rows sorted alphabetically based off of that resulting column. What I'm looking for would be:

```
... | About some more text  |...
... | Flipped text here     |...
... | Some text here        |...
```

The following is what I'm using to retrieve and display said data, but my understanding of Perl is sorely lacking. I don't understand how the @$data works, just know that it does. My failed sorting attempt is commented out by the #.

```
$data = $sth->fetchall_arrayref();
$sth->finish;

foreach $data ( @$data) {
    ($a, $name, $c, $d, $e, $f) = @$data;
    # @$data = sort { "\L$a->out_name([2])" cmp "\L$b->out_name([2])"} @$data;
    $Response->Write($a.",".out_name($name).",".$c.",".$d.",".$e.",".$f."<br />");
}
```

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

**EDIT**: I failed to note, the '0001:' portion may appear as '511:' or '85000:', that number isn't a constant length. If there's a way to deal with this condition in Mysql, that would be excellent. It didn't seem like a possibility in my searches, thus why I was attempting it with Perl.

Comment: Why is this tagged `asp-classic`?

Comment: I'm working with Classic ASP/PerlScript for displaying to the webpage. Wasn't sure if I should include the tag or not, erred on the side of generality.

Comment: That's fair enough, I didn't spot the `Response->Write`.

Comment: @thirtydot: I removed the tag, it really doesn't concern Classic ASP on second thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the database to do the sorting for you:

```
SELECT ...
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY SUBSTR(yourcolumn, 5)
```

Comment: Is there anyway that could be regex'd, instead of a constant character count? The size of the initial number may change over time.

Comment: not regexed, but: `order by substring(yourcolumn, instr(yourcolumn, ':')+2)`

Comment: @ysth: Thanks, that seems to work for now. This seems to work without the +2, any particular reason to leave the +2 in?

Comment: no, no reason, except to isolate exactly what you said without the leading ": "

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explanation of `@$data` related stuff. The DBI method

```
$data = $sth->fetchall_arrayref();
```

returns reference to an array of rows, where each is reference to array of columns. The foreach uses dereference to traverse first arrayref (I am using more descriptive variable names)

```
foreach $row_ref (@$data) {
```

Then each row is decomposed to individual columns using list assignment and dereference

```
($a, $name, $c, $d, $e, $f) = @$row_ref;
```

Your sort attempt failed because you tried to sort each row individually. It should rather look like this

```
foreach my $row_ref (sort { out_name($a->[1]) cmp out_name($b->[1]) } @$data) {
     ....
}
```

Also consider sorting on database query level suggested by Mark Byers, it might be better approach.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I'm trying to get this to work as a back up. Running into a problem with: `foreach my $row_ref (sort { out_name($a->[1]) cmp out_name($b->[1]) } @$data)` All that comes out of that is the last result, times the original number of results. I have this foreach outside (and following) the previous foreach. Any extra comments would be much appreciated.

Comment: @slitomonous - the sort have to be in outer foreach loop, because you need to sort all rows. `$a` and `$b` variables are aliases to two rows that can be compared, my example shows comparison of second column processed by your `out_name` function. If you need more help, please post some code you have.

Answer (score 0):

Having the database sort for you will probably be faster, but if you want to/have to do it in perl, something like this should work:

```
@sorted_data = sort {
    my ($x) = ($a->[1] =~ m/^\d+: (.*)/); 
    my ($y) = ($b->[1] =~ m/^\d+: (.*)/);
    $x cmp $y;
} @$data;

foreach (@sorted_data) { print output }
```

[1] is the position of the column of interest in the @$data array, hardcoding the index is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

`@$data` (the first one) contains all the results from your query, and you should be sorting it *outside* your `foreach` block.

```
@sorted_data = sort { 
    my($x=$a) =~ s/^\d+: //; 
    my($y=$b) =~ s/^\d+: //;
    $x cmp $y
} @$data;
foreach my $data (@sorted_data) { 
   ... 
}
```

(Reusing `$data` and `@$data` the way you did is syntactically valid but hella confusing)

Answer (score 0):

My first proposision is to hold this column in two different columns. To join them is always easier than separate them dynamically.

Comment: I don't have that option, unfortunately.